# insert values into mysql table from jtextfield java GUI

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, user-interface

I use this code when i press button , it should insert values into database

```
 code  else if(a.getSource()==New){

          try{
            if(Cpphone.getText().equals("")||Dnname.getText().equals("")||array.equals("")|| totalcost==0)
               {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                 "Please insert all information before submitting.", "", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
            else{          
            Connection mycon= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projectofpharmacy","root","sherouk");
            Statement mystat=mycon.createStatement();

            mystat.executeUpdate("insert into pharmacy_orders (patintphone,doctorName,OrderdateTime,totalCost) values ('"+Cpphone.getText()+"','"+Dnname.getText()+"',now(),'"+totalcost+"'");
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                 "the process is done successfuly.", "", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

           array=null;
           totalcost=0;

        }   
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);

             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                 e.toString(), "", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    }
```

}

> I get this error (java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in now() method.
Try something like:

```
private static java.sql.Date getCurrentDate() {
    java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
    return new java.sql.Date(today.getTime());
}

String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER"
    + "(USER_ID, USERNAME, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE) VALUES"
    + "(?,?,?,?)";
preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
preparedStatement.setDate(4, getCurrentDate());
```